# Convert Scripted Jenkinsfile to Declarative script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, bcbsn

The plugin doesn't provide declarative script. How can I convert it from scripted to declarative?

The url : https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-build-status-notifier-plugin

```
  ...
  stage 'Build'
    bitbucketStatusNotify(
      buildState: 'INPROGRESS',
      buildKey: 'build',
      buildName: 'Build',
      repoSlug: 'my-awesome-project',
      commitId: 'a83c709e9d514421ef614ef0a1117366c84c6304'      
    )
  try {
        myBuildFunction()
        bitbucketStatusNotify(
          buildState: 'SUCCESSFUL',
          buildKey: 'build',
          buildName: 'Build',
          repoSlug: 'my-awesome-project',
          commitId: 'a83c709e9d514421ef614ef0a1117366c84c6304'          
        )
  }catch(Exception e) {
          bitbucketStatusNotify(
          buildState: 'FAILED',
          buildKey: 'build',
          buildName: 'Build',
          buildDescription: 'Something went wrong with build!',
          repoSlug: 'my-awesome-project',
          commitId: 'a83c709e9d514421ef614ef0a1117366c84c6304'      
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the code for the plugin indicates that the APIs shown in the example are build steps so you can do something like:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('start') {
            steps {
                bitbucketStatusNotify(buildState: 'INPROGRESS' .... )
            }
        }
            .
            .
        stage('last') {
            steps {
                .
                .
                bitbucketStatusNotify(buildState: 'SUCCESSFUL' ... )
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        failure {
            bitbucketStatusNotify(buildState: 'FAILURE' ... )
        }
    }
}
```